# Stability of trivial solution of the $dx_t = 5x_tdt + 2019x_tdW_t$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

> Let $x_t = 0$ be a trivial random process. Check if it is a solution for the SDE $dx_t = 5x_tdt + 2019x_tdW_t$ (where $W_t$ is Wiener process). If it is - then check wheather is it stable.

It is clear that $x_t$ is a solution for the given SDE. I also know that gerneral solution is of the form $X_0 \operatorname{exp}((5-\frac{2019^2}{2})t + 2019W_t)$. But from this moment I can't neither prove that solution is stable nor that it is unstable.

So any help is appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "stable"?